# How is the window property console different?

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I open my chrome console and type `clear()` how is `window.console.clear()` invoked even though `this` is in the context of window?

and how does assigning a method to console is not working when invoked directly like `console()` ?

```
this.console.clear2 = function(){this.clear()}
clear2(); //ReferenceError: clear2 is not defined
this.console.clear2() //works fine
```

what's happening in these cases ?

Comment: `clear()` is probably a console only helper command - like `$` and `$$` and `$_` etc [MDN has documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) for such helpers

Comment: `clear` is just a function in scope. It’s not the same as `console.clear` (try `clear === console.clear`).

Comment: According to my console, `clear` is a "Command Line API" and `console.clear` is "native code".   May well be that one is just a shortcut to the other, but they're not the same object.

Comment: It is now clear what is happening in the case of console. Great explanations!